# Texture in render does not appear the same as it is in 3D view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I got the UV sphere texture and all that, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc0b5GcYl3U).

It looks good in in 3D view but is not similar at all when I render it.

[image: The image viewing through camera]

[image: Render]

[image: Nodes]

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what's wrong with it. Can you upload an image that makes the seam more obvious?

Comment: Also, is the first image from the perspective of the camera?

Answer (score 1):

### Viewport texture coordinates

The texture in the 3D view while using cycles are currently (2.77a) placed on the object's surface using the info from the **selected UVmap**, not from the node tree.

In your case the image you see in the 3D view in texured mode (UV) is probably placed in a different way than how it would with the material's coordintes for the texture /Generated).

Nodes just don't work (yet) "live" whith the material's node setup.

I personally think it will be improved and work the way you tried, there are already some signals around (e.g. it works already for the [world background](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAMugm3JglU), it is one of the target of the [viewport redesign project](https://code.blender.org/2014/09/viewport-project-targets-current-state-of-the-code/)...), but at the moment, in order to get the result of your node setup, you must use the **rendered view**.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your texture; it's the lighting in your scene. Try aligning the lamp with the position of the camera:

[image]

Before

[image]

After

This is also the render result before and after the change:

[image]

Before

[image]

After

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

=Puck

Comment: I don't think he's asking about the shading. I think he's asking about the texture seam.

Comment: @Matt I believe shading created the texture seam.

Comment: ?? I don't understand how that could be possible...

Comment: In an unlit world, like the one shown in the question, one-lamp lighting could easily lead to the seam displayed in the render. Without a .blend file, this was my diagnosis. If you have a better one, please share it. @Matt

Comment: ...I'm pretty sure you and I are talking about a different "seam."

Comment: This is the seam I'm talking about. Is this the seam you're talking about? https://flic.kr/p/HeTyNP

Comment: @Matt Maybe I wasn't clear, but I was talking about where color meets black around the middle of the sphere.

Comment: Yeah... I don't think that's what the OP is talking about, but we won't know for sure until they add some info.

Comment: @Matt True. I am adding this to get past 15 characters.

Comment: @ShadyPuck I tried readjusting the lighting and still ended up with such seams http://imgur.com/a/xg3rP Here's the blend file https://www.dropbox.com/s/igtep9joffyx06o/Space%20Animation.blend?dl=0 and texture http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9DvzmslTIME/TQrT5bEDbII/AAAAAAAAAi4/q0jL2oQ_4rk/s1600/planet_Trask1200.png

Comment: Ok, I changed it from box to sphere on the image texture node and it fixed the seams (Didn't know I could do that before because I was running a year and a half older version of Blender until now. Just realized that it wasn't up to date) but it still has these weird lines running up and down the surface of it http://imgur.com/gWAUfwY